# Centos 7 CURL issuer certificate invalid

Tags: linux, centos7, curl

Using this CURL syntax bellow

```
curl --header "Content-type: application/json" --request POST --data '{ "userID" : "***", "securityCode":"***", "token":"***" }' https://12.12.12.12:1234/hhh/AAA/bbb
```

Produce this error

> curl: (60) Issuer certificate is invalid. More details here:
>   http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a
>   "bundle"  of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the
>   default  bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
>   using the --cacert option. If this HTTPS server uses a certificate
>   signed by a CA represented in  the bundle, the certificate
>   verification probably failed due to a  problem with the certificate
>   (it might be expired, or the name might  not match the domain name in
>   the URL). If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the
>   certificate, use  the -k (or --insecure) option

Have try this method

```
curl https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ca-bundle.crt

update-ca-trust
```

Still doesn't works. I'm don't want to use `-k` option, it just workaround solution for insecure connection. Have anybody facing same issue? Please share. Thank you

Ps.
On Centos 7 environment

Comment: Well, who is the issuer of your certificate? The documentation linked in the error message provides everything you need to solve this (and it's not the method you tried).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate of the server is either not trusted or does not list 12.12.12.12 as a verified IP address. You could use the output of

```
    openssl s_client -showcerts -connect 12.12.12.12:1234 </dev/null
```

to inspect the certificates and see what exactly the problem is.

Comment: its produce `unknown option -dumpcerts`

Comment: @YohanesAI check the docs for openssl s_client you will find the answer there.